# Can CanvasKit-based Flutter web app be embedded in other (non-Flutter) web apps/websites?

Tags: flutter, dart, iframe, web-component, canvaskit

We're planning to build a Flutter web app that will need to be embedded within partners' websites (built with different web technologies). We have to use `CanvasKit` as rendering performance is important (it's a non-trivial component).

As far as I've researched, `Web Components` support is not available for Flutter for now (correct me if that's wrong). So the only method of embedding I can think of is an `iframe`. As `CanvasKit` relies on `WebAssembly`, I'm concerned about whether that will work as intended. So my question is this: is it possible to embed `CanvasKit`-based Flatter web apps within other (non-Flutter) web apps, and if so - does it have any downsides worth mentioning, compared to "typical" web apps (e.g., those built with `React`).

I have to decide strategically for my team whether to use Flutter for such a project or stick to a traditional web stack. Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently writing a flutter project for the web that is embedded in the web via `iframe`. Everything works fine, at first it was difficult how to pass parameters inside flutter (to interact with the server (id / additional options etc)) solved this issue through query parameters in a web browser and get inside flutter through (GETX package `Get.parameters['']`).My opinion.... Before starting global development, write a simple project that could interact inside your site, embed in iframe and pass any parameters)

Comment: Are you using CanvasKit? (I.e., `--web-renderer canvaskit`)

Comment: flutter build web --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_CANVASKIT_URL=./canvaskit/